# Fourier Transformation help

Tags: c#, math, image-processing

I'm suppose to do some work with Fourier transformations and I'm still really confused.

I'm given a signal (in this case it is f[t] = sin(2 pi s t / N) where s = 8 and N = 128)

And I'm suppose to find the Real, Imaginary, Phase, and Magnitude.

I understand how to get the Real and Imaginary, but the Phase and the Magnitude are beyond me...

the sudo code for getting the Real and the Imaginary is:

```
for u = 0 to M-1 do
F[u].real = 0
F[u].imag = 0
for x = 0 to M-1 do
    F[u].real += f[x] * cos(- 2 * pi * u * x / M)
    F[u].imag += f[x] * sin(- 2 * pi * u * x / M)
end do
F[u].real /= M
F[u].imag /= M
end do
```

Now somewhere in there is the phase and the magnitude, but where?!

Thanks!

Also, some programmer-equse explination of the basics of FTs would be wonderful as well!

Comment: mmm belongs to http://math.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you think to real and imaginary components as coordinates in an XY plane then the phase is the angle between the vector and the X+ axis, and the magnitude is the length of the vector.
To compute then you just need

```
magnitude = sqrt(real*real + imag*imag)
phase = atan2(imag, real)
```

Answer (score 3):

From http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_number#Absolute_value_and_argument:

- The magnitude is `sqrt(real^2 + imag^2)` (where `^` denotes "squared").
- The phase is `atan2(imag, real)` (where `atan2()` denotes the two-argument arctan function).

That Wikipedia article explains *why* better than I can do justice here.

Comment: +1 Thank you for the link.  The wiki for Fourier Transformation didn't have (as far as I could tell) any of that info.